# Extend ASP.NET MVC ViewResult with Custom Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For my asp.net mvc project, whenever I return a view, I append a couple of properties in a base controller by overriding the OnActionExecuted method like so:

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.Result.GetType() == typeof(ViewResult))
        {
            var action = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
            action.ViewBag.ClientSettings = ClientSettings;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
```

I'm currently sticking the ClientSettings in the ViewBag and then accessing it in the view from the viewbag.

What I would really like is for the action itself to have the ClientSettings property directly on the ViewResult so that I can in turn, access it directly from the view but I'm not quite sure how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using strongly typed views and store things like you described in model properties.

Your case (base controller code):

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    var viewModel = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model as ViewModelBase;
    if (viewModel != null)
    {
        viewModel.ClientSettings = ClientSettings;
    }

    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

Now if your view model is inherited from ViewModelBase you can set ClientSettings from the base controller and access it in your views via `Model` property of `ViewPage<T>`.

Comment: Thanks... I think this is the approach I'm going to have to take... it's not exactly what I was after, but it'll do.